# Save TCA changes in TYPO3 on select box

Tags: drop-down-menu, typo3, onchange

I created I new field in my TCA. I want to list all articles and select one, to set the article as top-article.

The articles have a UID and the database a column called istoparticle.
tx_vendor_domain_model_article is the table with all infos of the article.

I added a TCAcolumn.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', array(
    'tx_test_istoparticle' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'onChange' => 'reload',
        'label' => 'Top Article',
        'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'itemsProcFunc' => \Vendor\MyArticles\Hooks\Backend\Preview\ArticleRenderer::class . '->getArticleTitle',

        )
    ),
));
```

With a userfunction

```
public function getTopArticles($param){
    $pid = $param['row']['pid'];
    $articles = $this->getArticles($pid);

    foreach ($articles as $article) {

        $record = BackendUtility::getRecord('tx_vendor_domain_model_article', $article->getUid());
        $title = $record['header'];
        $param['items'][][] = $title;
    }
}
```

BTW:$record has all infos that I need, UID, bodytext and so on. But I can only store the header in the array!?
Now I got all the titles listed in my selectbox in the backend.

What do I have to do, to save my toparticle If I select an article in the backend?

Is there a onChange method for the TCA? And how can I get the infos like the Uid if I select one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items in TCA configuration should have at least two elements - first one is the label and second is the value. There are more options, but I think not needed in your case. You can read about them here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#items

It means your usefFunc should look like that:

```
public function getTopArticles(&$param){
    $pid = $param['row']['pid'];
    $teasers = $this->getArticles($pid);

    foreach ($articles as $article) {

        $record = BackendUtility::getRecord('tx_vendor_domain_model_article', $article->getUid());
        $param['items'][] = [
            $record['header'],
            $record['uid'],
        ]
    }
}
```

And yes, there is `onChange` functionality in TCA:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/Columns/Index.html?highlight=onchange#onchange

If you are using older TYPO3 than 8.6 you would need to look for `requestUpdate` according to: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.6/Deprecation-78899-TCACtrlFieldRequestUpdateDropped.html